# bootstrap select - nativeElement.selectpicker is not a function - Angular 9

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular9, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to get searchable select box working with bootstrap in my Angular 9 project. For that I am using [bootstrap select.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-select)

Following is how I have implemented it.

In My template :-

```
<div class="form-group row">

  <label for="txnSubCategory" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-form-label">Transaction Sub Category</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
    <select #selectTxnSubCategory class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="txnSubCategory" data-width="100%"
      formControlName="txnSubCategory">
      <option data-tokens="ABCD" value="Yes" selected>ABCD</option>
      <option data-tokens="PQRS" value="No">PQRS</option>
      <option data-tokens="LMNO" value="No">LMNO</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

In the component :-

```
 @ViewChild('selectTxnSubCategory') selectTxnSubCategory: ElementRef;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.selectTxnSubCategory.nativeElement.selectpicker('refresh');
 }
```

In my package json I have made sure that bootstrap-select is placed after jquery. same with the angular.json file. So that bootstrap select does not get overridden by jquery.

However, when I run the program, I don't see my select dropdowns in the view. I get following error in the console.

```
core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: this.selectTxnSubCategory.nativeElement.selectpicker is not a function
    at BasicInfoComponent.ngAfterViewInit (basic-info.component.ts:33)
    at callHook (core.js:4726)
    at callHooks (core.js:4690)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4630)
    at refreshView (core.js:12088)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:13404)
    at refreshView (core.js:12035)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13458)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11729)
    at refreshView (core.js:12064)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: refer this https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2040

Comment: @NitinLawande I checked that too. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

native element doesn't have this property use Jquery for this. install and import library

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

then call

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: When I do this, I get selectpicker is not a function error

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it resolved. Not elegant, but working.

I removed all the styling, scripts from bootstrap, bootstrap select and jquery from angular.json file and added them into index.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.18/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.18/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

  <!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.18/dist/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

and in my component,

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';



ngAfterViewInit() {

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

}
```

That is how It went. :)

**Note:**

As @pc_coder has suggested [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62928824/3892439), I did add `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` in my component. But it did not work and I got the error selectpicker is not a function.

Later I realized that bootstrap select js might have been wiped out by a script that comes after it. But how; I had added the scripts in order.

Later found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11044) in github which described following.

> When you add a script or style to the angular.json file in angular@6+
> (or in angular-cli.json in angular@5orEarlier), the expected results
> is that those js files whether they are bootstrap.min.css or
> jquery.min.js will get processed and combined into the new style.js or
> scripts.js files.

According to that, there is one js which bundle all the script files that are in the angular.json file. In that, the order of the scripts **might not** be in the order i wanted them to be.

So I ended up removing them from angular.json file and placed cdn urls in index.html in the order I want them to be.